# Two-digit primes in arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I found this problem:

> Four two-digit primes $a,b,c$, and $d$ form an increasing arithmetic sequence with $a > 5$ and common difference 6.  What is the value of $\dfrac{a + b}{c + d}$?

but I can't seem to find a way to solve it. I know from brute force that $a = 41, b = 47, c = 53$, and $d = 59$, and so $\dfrac{a + b}{c + d} = \dfrac{11}{14}$. How can I solve this problem without brute force?

Comment: Brute force is really the only way. Odd to have the condition that $a>5$ along with the condition that $a$ is a $2$-digit number, which traditionally means $100>a\geq 10.$

Comment: they cannot be divisible by 5, which means that the first one is $1 \pmod 5 $ and so $1 \pmod{10}$ To begin $11, 17, 23, 29$  with ratio $\frac{28}{52}= \frac{7}{13}$ Not really a single correct answer

Comment: I assume $a \gt 5$ is to rule out $5,11,17,23$, overlooking the fact that it was ruled out by the fact that $a$ has two digits.

Comment: I would say your effort is mostly in vain. In concurrence with @ThomasAndrews, I would say that it's really not that bad to check all the two-digit primes- there's only 21 possible choices in the first place, and the last three aren't possible because the next three after them aren't all two-digit. Checking 18 cases isn't that bad. But if you must reduce the number of cases, I concur with JimmyK4542's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the primes have a common difference of $6$, let the primes be $a, a+6, a+12, a+18$.

Since $a > 5$, none of the primes can be $0\pmod{5}$. Hence, $a,a+6,a+12,a+18 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. Solving each of these individually yields $a \not\equiv 0, 4, 3, 2 \pmod{5}$. Therefore, $a \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Also, since $a > 5$ is prime, $a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{6}$.

If $a \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $a \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$, then by the Chinese remainder theorem, $a \equiv 1 \pmod{30}$. If $a \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $a \equiv -1 \pmod{6}$, then by the Chinese remainder theorem, $a \equiv 11 \pmod{30}$.

So you just need to check two digit numbers $a$ which are either $1$ or $11$ modulo $30$. These are $a = 11, 31, 41, 61, 71, 91$. There is still a bit of brute force involved, but it's a bit better than checking every two digit prime.

Comment: Thank you! However, since $91 = 7 \times 13$, we only need check $a = 11, 31, 41, 61, 71$.